# Jquery if text contains specific text change sibling select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I want to write some jquery that says if .email div contains "uic.edu" assign sibling select value to 2.

My code below is changing all selects on the page to a value of 2...How do I single out only the "selects" within .department-user that have the email which contains 'uic.edu'?

**JS:**

```
if ($(".department-user:contains('uic.edu')")) {
    $(".department-user select").val("2");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="department-user">
    <div class="email">john@uic.edu</div>
    <div class="quick-assign">
        <select name="" id="">
            <option value="0">Michigan</option>
            <option value="1">california</option>
            <option value="2">Chicago</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".department-user:contains('uic.edu') .quick-assign > select").val(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there! You just needed to select the correct element for the text check. Also, it's a better idea to throw a condition like this as its own variable to increase your codes readability.

```
var isUicEdu = $(".department-user .email:contains('uic.edu')").length;

if (isUicEdu) {
    $(isUicEdu).siblings('.quick-assign').children('select').val("2");
}
```

Comment: hmm it looks like this still goes through and changes all selects to the value of 2. I have a list of over 200 users and need to only change the select if the email div contains that text. does that make sense?

Comment: @whatsnewsaes fair enough - tweaked the answer so it should work for this scenario

Comment: +1 `isUicEdu` will return a jQuery object even if it doesn't find anything and always be truthy. Add `.length` to your if statement/variable to detect if jQuery actually found the element. https://jsfiddle.net/1rshwtu8/5/

Comment: Thank you @Dave. My bad... Need to stop answering SO questions on a Sunday night!

Answer (score 1):

One approach, in plain JavaScript, is the following:

```
// a map of which domains map to which
// location (the values of the <select>):
var domainLocationMap = {
  'uic.edu': 'Chicago'
};


function selectFromDomain(node) {

  // the email is the text-content of the passed-in
  // node after that text-content is stripped of
  // leading and trailing white-space:
  let email = node.textContent.trim(),

    // using the Element.closest() method to find
    // the first ancestor element that matches the
    // supplied CSS selector:
    user = node.closest('li.department-user'),

    // using the querySelector() method to find the first,
    // if any should exist, element matching the supplied
    // CSS selector:
    select = user.querySelector('select'),

    // retrieving the substring of the email String
    // using String.prototype.substring(), setting
    // the first index to the index of the first
    // occurrence of the '@' character, and increasing
    // that index by 1 to remove that character from
    // the result:
    domain = email.substring(email.indexOf('@') + 1);

  // converting the children of the <select> element
  // to an Array, using Array.from(); and then filtering
  // that Array to retain only those <option> elements
  // whose text property is equal to the property of the 
  // domainLocationMap property with the key of the domain:
  Array.from(select.children).filter(function (opt) {
    return opt.text === domainLocationMap[ domain ];

  // Array.prototype.filter() returns the results of the
  // filtering, and here we iterate over that Array
  // using Array.prototype.forEach, with Arrow syntax,
  // to set the retained options ('opt') 'selected' property
  // to true:
  }).forEach(opt => opt.selected = true);

}

// converting the results document.querySelectorAll() to an Array,
// again using Array.from() and then iterating over the Array with
// Array.prototype.forEach(); calling the above function for each
// of the found <div class="email"> elements (if any were found):
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.email')).forEach(function(mail) {
  selectFromDomain(mail);
});
```

```js
var domainLocationMap = {
  'uic.edu': 'Chicago'
};

function selectFromDomain(node) {
  let email = node.textContent.trim(),
    user = node.closest('li.department-user'),
    select = user.querySelector('select'),
    domain = email.substring(email.indexOf('@') + 1);

  Array.from(select.children).filter(function(opt) {
    return opt.text === domainLocationMap[domain];
  }).forEach(opt => opt.selected = true);

}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.email')).forEach(function(mail) {
  selectFromDomain(mail);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="department-user">
    <div class="email">john@uic.edu</div>
    <div class="quick-assign">
      <select>
        <option value="0">Michigan</option>
        <option value="1">california</option>
        <option value="2">Chicago</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Comment: What a thought out answer!!

Comment: Thank you ever so much! It's just worth noting that, increasingly nowadays, jQuery isn't necessarily the requirement it once was :)